# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un archivo cuyo nombre contiene el carácter almohadilla "#"?

Tags: linux, unix

He tratado de eliminar este archivo llamado `#ç#` pero no he podido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues creo que es un problema con el signo #, recomiendan usar rm '#' *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si por algún caso no hubiera forma de borrarlo, con el **número de inodo** es sencillo.

Listamos el fichero:

```
$ ll
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Tcalids Tcalids        0 Jan 21 09:53 #
```

Miramos cuál es su inodo:

```
$ ls -li *#*
1062419 -rw-rw-r-- 1 Tcalids Tcalids 0 Jan 21 09:53 #
```

Utilizamos `find` para eliminar el fichero dado por ese número de inodo:

```
$ find . -inum 1062419 -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular empty file ‘./#’? y
```

Comment: Wow de un problema que parecia sencillo se pueden aprender muchas cosas

Answer (score 5):

La carpera inicia con un caracter especial por lo que hay que agregar `\`. Para borrar la carpeta basta con ejectutar el siguiente comando

```sh
$ rm -rf \#ç#
```

Ésto situado en la ruta donde se encuentra dicho directorio

Comment: Gracias buen hombre si funciono

Comment: @Cesar o puedes poner comillas: `rm '#ç#'`

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que el caracter `#` en bash, se refiere al inicio de un comentario, es decir.

```
comando1 parametro 1 #parametro2
                      |_________ Todo lo que esté después del signo # será tratado como comentario.
```

Eso lo puedes revisar en el manual de bash, el cual establece.

> **COMMENTS**
>
> ```
> In a non-interactive shell, or an interactive shell in which the 
> interactive_comments option to the shopt builtin is enabled (see SHELL 
> BUILTIN COMMANDS below), a word beginning with # causes that word and all
> remaining characters on that line to be ignored. An interactive shell 
> without the interactive_comments option enabled does not allow comments.
> The interactive_comments option is on by default in interactive shells.
> ```

Entonces `rm -r #ç#` lo que hace es únicamente pasar un `rm -r` puesto que es ignorado lo que esté después del signo `#`.

De ahí que te mencione ese error. El comando necesita tener al menos un parámetro para borrar, es decir, un token diferente a un comentario.

Las opciones que puedes hacer, además de escapar con `\#` como ya se mencionó, son:

- #### Entrecomillar

  ```
  $ rm "#ç#"
  $ rm '#ç#'
  ```

  Entrecomillar evita ciertos caracteres adquieran significados especiales, en este caso hablamos de la capacidad de comentar que tiene `#`.

  Las comillas simples guardan el contenido literal de cada caracter dentro de ellas, en cambio, las comillas dobles tienen algunas excepciones, como los caracteres $, `, \ y !
- #### Utilizar el autocompletado.

  Para evitar este tipo de situaciones, busca utilizar el autocompletado de una shell que lo permite, por ejemplo, `zsh` `fish`

  Sólo pones `rm <tab>` (osea que presionas tab) y te autocompletará la opción y podrás navegar entre ellas con las flechas de navegación.

  Por ejemplo, con `zsh`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  O con `fish`.

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- #### Desactivar la opción de comentarios interactivos.

  Si tienes la maravillosa capacidad de comentar en la terminal, es por la opción de `interactive_comments` que está habilitada por defecto en la shell (al menos en el caso de bash), entonces puedes deshabilitar esa opción con el *built-in* `shopt`

  ```
  $ shopt -u interactive_comments
  ```

  Y ahora si puedes poner un signo de `#` y **no** será tratado como comentario.

  Es decir, ya puedes poner `$ rm #ç#`, osea, **sin escapar ni entrecomillar**

  Para volver a la normalidad, tendrías que volver a habilitar esa característica de bash.

  ```
  $ shopt -s interactive_comments
  ```

Comment: Exelente informacion gracias por la respuesta